Change colour/shape of points on PCoA (using vegan) and include arrows using metadata
I have metagenomic sequencing data with read abundances for several species (organized as a table of species and read abundances for each of my samples), along with a metadata file with information about collection date and collection location that I'd like to incorporate into the graph as well for visualization purposes. I was asked to do a PCoA on these data, and I've been able to make a figure that's got everything I need, except that I've also been tasked with seeing if I can change the points on the graph to match specific symbol/colour combinations that correspond to earlier graphs I've made for these data, rather than the default sample name labels.
In short, I've been doing the following with my own data and getting the expected output, but for the purposes of this example, I'm using the included test dataset:
    library(vegan)
    library(ape)
    dist <- vegdist(varespec,  method = "bray")
    PCOA <- pcoa(dist)
    PCOA <- pcoa(dist, correction = "cailliez")
    biplot.pcoa(PCOA)
    biplot.pcoa(PCOA, varespec) #to add the species onto the plot

However, I want to be able to change the colour and shapes of the points, rather than have the sample name used as the marker for each sample's coordinate. I'm able to partially get around this by using ggplot2 to graph Axis.1 and Axis.2 from the PCoA analysis and adjust the colours/shapes manually in the aes() part of the command, but then I miss out on the arrows for the variables (species in this case; possibly called descriptors of ordination - I'm new to these analyses and I'm not sure about all the nomenclature). I'd like to otherwise preserve everything about the initial biplot I got from the last step (biplot.pcoa(PCOA, varespec)), except for changing the way the points look to match the colour palette and shapes I used previously.
Any advice to make this work or is this just not possible to do for a PCoA done this way?
Thanks!

I think this Q & A will help. if you want a true biplot with ggplot2. If you want to use the same function (biplot.pcoa), you can use all of the arguments listed with the function biplot (e.g., labels, colors, etc.).

vegan does not have function pcoa, neither biplot.pcoa. Not a vegan issue.
